# advanced select distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to sql and need to do this:
I have a table named sec_users_table.
It looks like this:

```
id      ip      user_id      to_dt
--------------------------------------------------
1       1        1           26-Apr-12 2:14:02 PM
2       1        1           30-Apr-12 8:48:49 PM
3       1        1           02-May-12 6:17:22 PM
4       2        5           05-May-12 6:18:10 PM
5       2        5           04-May-12 6:17:57 PM
6       3        8           07-May-12 1:32:34 PM
7       3        8           09-May-12 5:09:54 PM
8       4        10          10-May-12 4:40:42 PM
9       5        12          11-May-12 6:10:29 PM
```

I want to select the unique pairs (ip, user_id) with the newest date, but to return just the id and ip columns. The result for this example would be:

```
id      ip
-----------
3       1  
4       2 
7       3  
8       4  
9       5
```

I'm using oracle pl/sql.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `user_id` relevant here? are `ip` and `user_id` always in a 1-1 correspondence? If not, could you expand your example to indicate what should happen? If so, what's the relevance of `user_id` to the question (and why is it being stored as a separate column in this table)?

Comment: Is TO_DT unique within (IP, USERID) ?

Comment: @APC I think that it is not guaranteed that a timestamp is unique, however, the probability that a user accesses from 2 ips at the same time is low.

Comment: The relevance is this.I must write a query wich return the Id (so I can later based on the Id, in my code get any colum and row I want) and the Ip (so the predefined engine can show the is as a search result). Later, based on the Id information I get the user_id key and show the user on the web page. But I don't want more than one equal pair (user_id, ip), because than I would have two same search result (for both Ip-s I get the same User). The latest date I need for something that involves isplaying the session for that user.

Answer (score 3):

You may try execute the following statement. The idea is to use rank over ip and user_id and sort them by date:

```
SELECT id, ip
FROM (
  SELECT id as id,
         ip as ip,
  rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ip, user_id ORDER BY to_dt DESC) as rk
  FROM sec_users_table
)
WHERE rk = 1;
```

[Sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba97d/1)

Comment: SQL Fiddle tip: you can copy and paste the OP's sample table of data in the "Text to DDL" tool to automatically generate the schema.  Should make working on these problems easier.  Here's what it would look like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42d8a

Comment: Thanks Jake, it will be much more easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at something like

```
SELECT s.id,
      s.ip
FROM sec_users_table s INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT ip,
          user_id,
          MAX(to_dt) last_date
  FROM sec_users_table
  GROUP BY ip,
          user_id
 ) m ON s.ip = m.ip
     and s.user_id = m.user_id
     and s.to_dt = m.last_date
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/58085/7/0)

Comment: SQL Fiddle tip: you can copy and paste the OP's sample table of data in the "Text to DDL" tool to automatically generate the schema. Should make working on these problems easier. Here's what it would look like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42d8a

Answer (score 0):

To get the most recent row for a given user:

```
SELECT id, ip
  FROM sec_users_table t
 WHERE to_dt = ( SELECT MAX(to_dt)
                   FROM sec_users_table t2
                  WHERE t2.user_id = t.user_id )
   AND user_id = :user
```

It would help performance to have an index on `user_id`.

If there is a risk you may have two equal dates, and you want to be sure the SQL return only a single row, you may want to add `AND ROWNMUN = 1`.